# Infer original type from index union type

Tags: typescript, types

Is there a way to infer an original type from a type union that was created as an index type? Here is an example.

```
class FooHandler { type: "Foo" = "Foo"; }
class GooHandler { type: "Goo" = "Goo"; }
class UniHandler { type: "A" | "B" | "C" = "A"; }

type HandlerVariant = FooHandler | GooHandler | UniHandler;
type HandlerTypeVariant = HandlerVariant["type"];

// Infer the concrete `HadnlerVariant`
type HandlerFromType<Type extends HandlerTypeVariant> = ??;
```

Ultimately, what I would like to be able to do is create a mapped type that for every `type` contains an instance of that type handler.

```
type HandlerRegistryType = {
    [Type in HandlerTypeVariant]: HandlerFromType<Type>;
}
```

**Edit:**

Seems like the accepted solution has some problems with deriving types in this more complex case. -Link to the ts playground-.

Additionally to the `type` from the code snippets above, I've added an `Id` and `CodeTemplate` of which both are specialized by `HandlerFromType<Type>`. After adding the `Id` everything works, but when I add the `CodeTemplate`, suddenly the type check fails as if the `HandlerFromType<Type>` is inferred to be all of the handlers.

**Edit2:**

I seem to have found the root of the problem. Here is the link to the minimal example on [ts playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgOwCYBsICcBqd0EtHBQC8UAYgPbnzJrpQA+UA4pdahgNwBQoksi7dABVwEbHgLF+NDOPwJgAbQBEvCMoC63HqOmDS6cgFsRkADxCANFACqUCAA9gEZAGcoAbyhqAXHtqmYjjyhAC+Umy0cgQAfFJQXFC29k4uSO52APwJSUIpzm62KmqaUNl2fggQAG4YiVCVNZxcOnwAwuRIEEIQRmAocM4W+WnukRgAQnCuEGbjwqLRCjFxJACCwMDCvf2Ds0Ixilqt0BtbPX0DQ3mOBen+k9Oz84FLwCtSXoNbfgDWECByAAzKAABRwwHwKAscVC2gAxgNXGMBLQpjMLLpbqMHgtIG84h56klfFBAlJlMooNNqQgQNwkkl4Z1ujsrhA-B0uhddkN5gZjIFMZAPiQjtxQi1EdN3BQqKiMCNCvN0bNlHLlITJdLkcxWAq6NjlQbVWZlCxyJrPKEgA). Since `HandlerFromType` has a default value for it's `U` template, when it's used inside the `CodeTemplate` this default value is used. Then in `codeTemplate` declaration an error `FooHandler` is not assignable to `GooHandler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Extract` type to get the members of a union that extend a certain type. This will work as you expect:

```
class FooHandler { type: "Foo" = "Foo"; }
class GooHandler { type: "Goo" = "Goo"; }

type HandlerVariant = FooHandler | GooHandler;
type HandlerTypeVariant = HandlerVariant["type"];

type HandlerFromType<Type extends HandlerTypeVariant> = Extract<HandlerVariant, { type: Type }>;

type HandlerRegistryType = {
    [Type in HandlerTypeVariant]: HandlerFromType<Type>;
}
```

**Edit**

A version that works well if `type` is a union in one of the members can be constructed but is a bit more convoluted and required distributed conditional types:

```
class FooHandler { type: "Foo" = "Foo"; foo: string }
class GooHandler { type: "Goo" = "Goo"; goo: string}
class UniHandler { type: "A" | "B" | "C" = "A"; uni: string}

type HandlerVariant = FooHandler | GooHandler | UniHandler;
type HandlerTypeVariant = HandlerVariant["type"];

type HandlerFromType<T, U extends { type: HandlerTypeVariant } = HandlerVariant> =  
  U extends U ? // Distribute over U, from here on U will be each meber of the union in turn 
  T extends U["type"] ? U : never // if the single elemnt T extends whatever union U has at type then we take U otherwise we remove it 
  : never; 


type HandlerRegistryType = {
  [Type in HandlerTypeVariant]: HandlerFromType<Type>;
}
// same as  { Foo: FooHandler; Goo: GooHandler; A: UniHandler; B: UniHandler; C: UniHandler; }
```

Comment: For handlers that use a union type for their `type` it does not work correctly. I'll add the example to the question.

Comment: @MarošBeťko Added a version that works for unions as well

Comment: I think I've encountered another problem with the implementation. This one is a bit more complicated so I've added a link to ts fiddle.

Comment: @MarošBeťko I'll have a look a bit later